# how to add multiple sheets to excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net, worksheet

i am adding multiple sheets to excel but it shows the exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))' . the exception occurs at Position: xlWorkBook.Sheets("105")

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet105 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlWorkSheet120 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlWorkSheet125 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlWorkSheet600 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
    xlWorkSheet105 = xlWorkBook.Sheets("105")
    xlWorkSheet120 = xlWorkBook.Sheets("120")
    xlWorkSheet125 = xlWorkBook.Sheets("125")
    xlWorkSheet600 = xlWorkBook.Sheets("600")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To add sheets, I think it should be something like `xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add`. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheetHeader As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlWorkSheet105 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlWorkSheet120 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlWorkSheet125 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlWorkSheet600 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlWorkSheetFooter As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
    xlWorkSheetHeader = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count))
    xlWorkSheetHeader.Name = "Header"
    xlWorkSheet105 = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count))
    xlWorkSheet105.Name = "105"
    xlWorkSheet120 = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count))
    xlWorkSheet120.Name = "120"
    xlWorkSheet125 = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count))
    xlWorkSheet125.Name = "125"
    xlWorkSheet600 = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count))
    xlWorkSheet600.Name = "600"
    xlWorkSheetFooter = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count))
    xlWorkSheetFooter.Name = "Footer"          xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Path)
```

This code work for me. In last I save the xlWorkBook